# How do I suppress my event-handling function from emitting unwanted text?

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, event-handling

I have a PowerShell script that composes a WinForms UI.  Here are the pertinent bits:

```
cls
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

Function FormClosed()
{
    $global:Canceled = $true
}

$global:MainForm = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$global:MainForm.add_FormClosed({FormClosed})

$global:MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

When I run the program, I get a PowerShell console window and the UI (as expected). When I click the main form control box "X", the function `FormClosed` is invoked (as expected). However, the text `Cancel` unexpectedly appears in the console window.

I put a breakpoint on `$global:Canceled = $true` in the function `FormClosed`. At this breakpoint, I step and then I see the execution pointer is on the `}` in `$global:MainForm.add_FormClosed({FormClosed})`. I step one more time and the text `Cancel` appears in the console window. So, I assume that the .NET `FormClosed` event is firing my `FormClosed` function (as expected) and my `FormClosed` function is emitting the text `Cancel`. I assume the text `Cancel` originated from the .NET `FormClosed` event.

How do I suppress my `FormClosed` function from emitting the text `Cancel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cancel` is returned from `ShowDialog` method, not from event handler. You can send it to Null:

```
$global:MainForm.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

See `ShowDialog` return value type (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) and `DialogResult` values (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx).